# extract action input parameters from model in .net using reflction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have this controller

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Authenticate(LoginUser model)
        {
        }
  }
```

And here is my input model

```
public class LoginUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string CaptchaCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use reflection to extract data .The example of data that I need this output

```
**Account:Authenticate:UserName ,Password ,CaptchaCode**
```

I find a code as you can see here :

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Club.Web.MvcApplication));

            var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
                    .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
                    .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, input = String.Join(",", x.GetParameters().Select(a => a.Name+"|"+a.ParameterType).ToArray()), Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();
```

But it returns

```
**Account:Authenticate:LoginUser**
```

But I need the item of my class

Comment: Then run reflection on the properties of the class?

Comment: @Llama how can  I do that Llama ?

Comment: You have `a.ParameterType` which gives you the `Type` object for `LoginUser`. You've already written all of the code above, so this should be simple for you.

Comment: @Llama you are right , My problem is how can I find the class by its name ?

Comment: What do you mean? You have a [`Type` not a `string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype?view=net-5.0)... the same as `asm.GetTypes()` returns a `Type[]`.

Comment: @Llama foreach (var item in controlleractionlist)
            {

                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
                propertyInfos = typeof(***).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                              BindingFlags.Static);
            } my question is what should I put instead *** .item.name ?

Comment: I think you're not looking at your code correctly. `AccountController` has a _method_ `Authenticate`. That method has a _parameter_ `LoginUser model`. The type here is `LoginUser` and the parameter name is `model`. The type `LoginUser` has 3 properties of type `string`: `UserName`, `Password`, and `CaptchaCode`. These 3 properties are not related to the `AccountController` class at all. P.S. As an FYI, `typeof(T)` returns a `Type`.